# MenuItem.MenuID Property for 'Save As Other' menu in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: c#-4.0, acrobat

I need to save a pdf file as Text(using c# code). So I am using 
"'Save As Other' -> 'Text'" option from 'File' menu in Acrobat reader.
But I am not able to find the menu id for 'Save As Other' -> 'Text'from File menu.

What is the menu id (MenuItem.MenuID property)for 'Save As Other' - Text option from File Menu in Adobe Acrobat Reader.
I am able to click File-> Open using Menu id for file = 1 and index for Open = 1 
But I am not able to find it for 'Save As Other' -> 'Text' option from File menu.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would have to verify it, but Acrobat Reader can not save as text; you'd need Acrobat for that.

Comment: The menu item name is "ADBE:SaveAsAccText" but there are dozens of better ways to extract text from a PDF other than using the free Reader in the manner you propose. It's also a violation of the license agreement and isn't guaranteed to work from version to version.

Comment: Thanks.. for providing the menu name. Other better ways like using libraries like itext ? Could you please elaborate it more as I am still novice to all this stuff?